# Querying on a set of parameters

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm stumped on this one.  I've tried everything I can think of, and been thwarted at every turn.

```
string[] s = {"a", "b", "c"};
string[] s2 = {"1", "2", "3"};
var s3 = s.Zip(s2, (first, second) => new string[] {first, second});

var ctx = db.Data.Where(x => x.SubList.All(y => s3
       .Any(z => y.SubListProp.Name == z[0] && y.Value == z[1])));
```

Assume the following:

Code first, EF6, Data, SubList, and SubListProp contain only the data you see in the this sample.

Obviously, this example doesn't work, as Array Indexers are not allowed in a SQL Expression.  The query works correctly if I add .AsEnumerable() to SubList, but that causes the test to occur client side, not on the sql server.  How can I generate a Linq to Entities query that will work with a set of parameterized pairs of data?

**Is it possible to modify this query to execute entirely on the sql server?  And if so, how?**

Comment: Honestly, you could do this with one query, but it would be so horribly inefficient because of relying on passing an array of strings that you need to compare with for every row in your table you just wouldn't want to. Break it up into a single query per item in s3.

Comment: @TravisJ - if there are 300 pairs, that's a lot of round trips.  using the AsEnumerable only round trips once, but is unreliable because the number of items returned could be large...

Comment: Come to chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: That would definitely be too many round trips. I think that sending that large of a string into the query could also cause significant slowdown. Is there any way to limit the amount of sets you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could combine the strings up front, and then project a string in order to use for the comparison like this:

```
string[] s = {"a", "b", "c"};
string[] s2 = {"1", "2", "3"};
IEnumerable<string> s3 = s.Zip(s2, (first, second) => first+second);//a1,b2,c3

var ctx = db.Data.Where(x => x.SubList
    .All(y => s3.Contains(y.SubListProp.Name + y.Value)));
```

Comment: I think that should do it.  Thanks.